# HTML/JS Replace image on navbar click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to replace an image at every click on the nav bar items.

Basically, I'm trying to get the same navbar behaviour as on that website  : http://jjhale.com/

This is what I've done so far :

The HTML file :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />       
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <!--JS Scripts-->
        <script src="scripts/onClick.js"></script>        

        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1><a id="name" href="Link_1.html">Test</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="slides-zone">
                <img id="image" src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" />
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="selected"><a href="Link_1.html" onclick="testFunction();">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Link_2.html">Link 2</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>        
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And my script that is supposed to replace images when any nav item is clicked :

```
var testFunction = function () {

    var element = document.getElementById('slides-zone');
    var img_to_replace = document.getElementById('image');

    var new_img = document.createElement("img");
    new_img.setAttribute('src', 'images/2.jpeg');
    new_img.setAttribute('alt', 'image_2');
    new_img.setAttribute('id', 'image')
    element.replaceChild(new_img, img_to_replace);

    return true;
}
```

I would like to have a solution/any info with Javascript only if possible, I prefer not using any framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First scan looks like it should work to me. Are you sure `images/2.jpeg` is correct? Should it be `images/2.jpg`? What is the exact behavior or error that is occurring?

Comment: Actually nothing happens, that's why I do not understand. The console does not show any errors either. And yes it is images/2.jpeg

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ozx3nyby/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#slides-zone {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function pictureChange() {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer2.jpg";
  }

  function pictureChange2() {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara4.jpg";
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1><a id="name" href="#">Test</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="slides-zone">
      <img id="theImage" src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg" />
      <img id="theImage" src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="selected" onclick="pictureChange();"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li onclick="pictureChange2();"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>
```

EDIT:  A few lines of jquery would be able to make you toggle the images easily

```
      $(function(){
  $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

and just name your files xyz_off.jpg and xyz_on.jpg etc...

Answer (score 2):

Using `onclick` on an anchor tag is a little tricky.
Try changing to this...

```
<a href="#" onclick="testFunction();">Link 1</a>
```

and the JavaScript to...

`return false;`

instead of

`return true;`

Comment: I like @rachel 's answer, I was @ work and didn't have time to formulate a proper answer.

Comment: i'm working on a badge at the moment and trying to get to 8000 so if you feel like voting up one of my answers, visit my profile by clicking on my name. I've nearly 500 to choose from! :)

Comment: Will do, my next badge has to do with voting.

Comment: one of my recent triumphs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772005/footer-appears-next-to-section-instead-of-bellow/31772214#31772214